# Square root of -1

Tags: complex-numbers, roots

Hello stackexchange users! I am somewhat confused on $\sqrt{-1}$. I believe the answer should be no solution, or inconsistent, or at least something in that nature. Am I correct or am I most likely wrong? Any help or insight would be deeply appreciated

Comment: Your answer is in the tags.

Comment: Could you please clarify?

Comment: Just look up imaginary and complex numbers on Wikipedia.

Comment: I asked this question on math.stackexchange.... I wasn't really looking for imaginary and complex numbers on Wikipedia. I simply wanted some clarification as you can see in my question.

Answer (score 0):

if you consider all polynomials to have roots you can ask what is the root of x^2+1 well it turns out that this is only 0 when x =sqrt(-1) so imagine we have a value, i ,for the x that solves it. you can ask what set it's in but positive*positive=negative * negative = positive, so no positive or negative number works. to make sure all polynomials have roots you need to invent imaginary numbers.